# Xamarin Forms SearchBar + ListView slow to update

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin, optimization, searchbar

I would like some help into speeding up the process of filtering a long list of list items and viewing them on a ListView.

My app has a search bar, a ListView and a very long list of strings to choose from.

When the user enter a search term, the ListView is updated with every key stroke and filter out the irrelevant items.

Sorting itself takes a few milliseconds, but updating the ListView afterwards with the new filter-event takes a long time (20 seconds easy, if only a single character has been entered as search criteria)

I believe the time is spent on inflating a large number of ViewCells every time the filtered list updates.

Do any of you know how to speed up the process? I thought the way it could work was to have a very limited number of ViewCells (like 10 or 20) and then have them update and just show a selection of the filtered list. Scrolling would to be reusing the top/bottom one, update the content and put it back on the bottom/top - but I have not been able to wrap my head around how to do this.

Maybe it is the wrong approach and you know a better way?

Comment: please share the relevant code

Comment: Also how many items do you have in your listview? Cause I have done something similar and its pretty efficient for about 200-300 items with barely any delay.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem that my list with just 20 elements would search extremely slow. Maybe your problem is similar. Sadly you didn't post any code. I had something like this:

```
List l = originalItems.Where((i) => i.Name.Contains(filterText));
listView.ItemsSource = l;
```

And I could not understand why this would be so slow. I found a different approach with more overhead that for some reason is faster and more responsive and overall feels better for the user. My `ListView` always has an `ObservableCollection` as `ItemsSource`. When I filter I calculate the difference to this `ObservableCollection` (the extra items and the removed items) and then remove or add accordingly. This avoids replacing the `ItemsSource` property which seems to be too harsh on the `ListView`.

```
//property of the class
ObservableCollection<FlightListItem> listViewItems;
// ....
//somewhere at initialization
listView.ItemsSoure = listViewItems;
// ....
//in the filter method:
List l = originalItems.Where((i) => i.Name.Contains(filterText));
IEnumerable itemsToAdd = l.Except(listViewItems).ToList();
IEnumerable itemsToRemove = listViewItems.Except(l).ToList();
listView.BeginRefresh();
foreach (FlightListItem item in removes)
    listViewItems.Remove(item);
foreach (FlightListItem item in added)
    listViewItems.Add(item);
listView.EndRefresh();
```

Notes:

- removing the `listView.BeginRefresh()` and `EndRefresh()` did not seem to impact performance, but it seems the right thing to call them here.
- We need to call `ToList()` on the `itemsToAdd` and `itemsToRemove` even though we only need `IEnumerables`! This is because `Except` is a lazy operation and will otherwise only be evaluated during the for loop. However during the for loop one of the parameters to Except changes which leads to an `IllegalArgumentException` due to modifying an `IEnumerable` while going over it.
- If anyone knows a good filterable observable collection that would probably be a nicer solution.